# Change timeout in Systemback

Tags: livedvd

I am learning to use Systemback in Lubuntu, in order to create a customized livecd/livedvd. I would like to change the main menu timeout to 0 and add rootdelay=5. How do i do this?
thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I forgot to say, it is the boot menu timeout I want to change.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the syslinux/syslinux.cfg (or isolinux/isolinux.cfg in the .iso) file after the Live image is created. You can repack the .sblive file or rebuild the .iso, or modify the file on the pendrive.
But if you using UEFI, then the EFI boot menu has no timeout...

Comment: I am new to linux . I do not khow how to edit the .iso file. Thanks in advance for any help.